# Paraview: how to enable the "Point Gaussian" option?

Tags: paraview

The version of Paraview is 5.4.1, so the representation option "Point Gaussian" should appear:

[image: Representation options]

But only "Points" shows... Any Paraview setting to enable?

Comment: Point Gaussian does not exist in ParaView 5.4.1, only after ParaView 5.5.

Comment: Synaptic doesn't show more recent versions than 5.4.1, Paraview must have stopped 32bit development at that moment...

Comment: What does this have to do with 32 bits ? If you are using Ubuntu, you should not use the package provided by synaptic, it is an outdated, unoptimized build.
You can download more recent version of ParaView here : https://www.paraview.org/download/

Comment: The build fails: **CMake Error at projects/unix/llvm.cmake:20 (message):
  Could not configure LLVM for the target system processor 'i686'.**

Comment: ParaView does not support 32bit indeed. Are you using an old CPU ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you want PointGaussian, you will have to use a 64bit os imo.

Comment: The computer is like 6 years old, but maybe I can change the CPU... Many thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, ParaView 5.4.1 doesn't implement « Point Gaussian », and later versions require 64bits CPUs...